# Powershell cannot Get data from Generated Textbox

Tags: powershell, winforms

[image: Example]

Making a small Budgeting app that populates bills from a list (in my Settings tab, this works fine).
Depending what you have for bills, it will generate what you see in screenshot (1 Label, 2 Textboxes, Calendar, and a Checkbox)

My Issue,
I can not seem to get data from any of these generated components. The goal is for all the Payment Due textboxes to add up their Sum to have a total. Here is what the generated function looks like.

```
function Generate-Bills
{
    $Due = @() # <- Array for Due Bills
    $coord = 40
    foreach ($bill in Get-Content "$path\House.txt") #<- list of bills stored in this text file
    {
        $BillName  = $bill
        $BillDue   = $bill + "Due"
        $BillNext  = $bill + "Next"
        $BillDate  = $bill + "Date"
        $BillCheck = $bill + "Check"
        
        Write-Host $BillName
        Write-Host $BillDue
        Write-Host $BillNext
        Write-Host $BillDate
        Write-Host $BillCheck
        Write-Host $coord
        
        $BillCheck = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
        $BillDate  = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker'
        $BillNext  = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
        $BillDue   = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
        $BillName  = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
        #
        # Checkbox
        #
        $BillCheck.Left = '478'
        $BillCheck.Top = $coord
        $BillCheck.Name = $BillCheck
        $BillCheck.Size = '104, 24'
        $BillCheck.TabIndex = 4
        $BillCheck.Text = 'Paid'
        $BillCheck.ForeColor = $textcolor
        $BillCheck.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
        $BillCheck.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
        $BillCheck.Anchor = 'Top'
        #
        # Due Date
        #
        $BillDate.Left = '360'
        $BillDate.Top = $coord
        $BillDate.Name = $BillDate
        $BillDate.Size = '110, 20'
        $BillDate.TabIndex = 3
        $BillDate.Format = 'Short'
        $BillDate.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt '
        $BillDate.Anchor = 'Top, Bottom'
        #
        # Next Payment
        #
        $BillNext.Left = '238'
        $BillNext.Top = $coord
        $BillNext.Name = $BillNext
        $BillNext.Size = '100, 20'
        $BillNext.TabIndex = 2
        $BillNext.Backcolor = '33, 35, 50'
        $BillNext.BorderStyle = 'None'
        $BillNext.ForeColor = 'White'
        $BillNext.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif, 18pt, style=Bold'
        $BillNext.Anchor = 'Top, Bottom'
        #
        # Due Payment
        #
        $BillDue.Left = '108'
        $BillDue.Top = $coord
        $BillDue.Name = $BillDue
        $BillDue.Size = '100, 20'
        $BillDue.TabIndex = 1
        $BillDue.Backcolor = '33, 35, 50'
        $BillDue.BorderStyle = 'None'
        $BillDue.ForeColor = 'White'
        $BillDue.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif, 18pt, style=Bold'
        $BillDue.Anchor = 'Top, Bottom'
        
    #Fail Attempt :(
    $BillDue.Add_TextChanged({Write-Host $BillDue.Text})

        #
        # Name of Bill
        #
        $BillName.AutoSize = $True
        $BillName.Left = '18'
        $BillName.Top = $coord
        $BillName.Name = $BillName
        $BillName.Size = '35, 17'
        $BillName.TabIndex = 0
        $BillName.Text = $bill
        $BillName.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif, 10pt, style=Bold'
        $BillName.ForeColor = 'White'
        $BillName.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
        $BillName.Anchor = 'Top, Bottom'
        #
        # Controls
        #
        $HouseGenPanel.Controls.Add($BillCheck)
        $HouseGenPanel.Controls.Add($BillDate)
        $HouseGenPanel.Controls.Add($BillNext)
        $HouseGenPanel.Controls.Add($BillDue)
        $HouseGenPanel.Controls.Add($BillName)
        
        $data += $BillDue.Text
        $coord += 50
        $HouseGenPanel.Height += 45
    }
    Write-Host $Due "data"      
}
```

I have tried getting it to store the textbox data into an array, but it will not let me pull it,
I have also tried making it so when the textbox updates, it reports the new numbers, but I cant seem to find a way for it to update each textbox properly.

Any Guidance on this is much appreciated as this is the only thing stopping me from finishing this app. (source code will be released on completion.)

== Solution ===

```
$global:controls = $HousePanel.controls

$output.Text = $global:controls['TextBox1'].text

$global:controls['TextBox1'].Add_TextChanged({ $output.Text = $global:controls['TextBox1'].text})
```

Add controls to a global variable, then call the generated .Name

Answer (score 0):

By throwing the controls into a global variable, I was able to access generated variables, and get their updated text with the following snippet.

```
$global:controls = $HousePanel.controls

$output.Text = $global:controls['TextBox1'].text

$global:controls['TextBox1'].Add_TextChanged({ $output.Text = $global:controls['TextBox1'].text})
```